# Problemas com SELECT option com PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Amigos reeditei a conexão PDO abaixo:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pbfjacar_site' , 'pbfjacar_murilo' , 'smc100164' );
$stmt = $conn-> prepare('SELECT font FROM fontes');
$stmt-> execute();
$result = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Para executar essa nova operação:

```
<select name="tipo_font_end">
<?php foreach( $result as $row ) ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['font'];?>"><?php echo $row['font'];?></option>

</select>
```

Mas não estou obtendo o resultado esperado, pois ele agora puxa somente o ultimo "ID" de um total de 10 cadastros na tabela "fontes", conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou inserindo o endereço de acesso para teste abaixo, para poderem ver o que esta acontecendo!
http://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/teste/end.php

Se os amigos puderem me mostrar onde estou errando ou ate mesmo o que esta faltando, ficarei muito agradecido.
Abraços a todos.

Comment: O seu `<select>` não tem loop?

Comment: Amigo o que seria loop? Sou muito leigo em php.

Comment: Antes dessa linha `return $result;` coloque isso `var_dump($result);`, se possível edite sua resposta com o resultado, ok?

Comment: Não funcionou!!! Entre no endereço (http://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/teste/end.php), e veja o resultado. O código ficou assim:
`<?php
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site", "root", "");
$count = 'SELECT * FROM fontes';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($count);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
return $result;
foreach($result as $res)
?>`

Comment: Murilo, notei que você editou totalmente sua publicação, o que acabou descaracterizando uma dúvida que poderia ser útil para outros, pois agora quem entrar aqui vai ver coisas totalmente fora de contexto. Se alguma resposta resolveu o seu problema você pode marcar como resolvido (não precisa colocar RESOLVIDO no título) e acrescentar informações nos comentários. Se você mesmo tiver resolvido, crie sua própria resposta. Mas é bom sempre manter sua dúvida inicial.

Comment: Peço desculpas Paulo, não irá acontecer novamente.

Answer (score 2):

```
$conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE' , 'USUARIO' , 'SENHA' );
$stmt = $conn-> prepare( 'SELECT * FROM fontes' );
$stmt-> execute();
$result = $stmt-> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

<select name="tipo_font_end">
    <?php foreach( $result as $row ) ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['font'];?>"><?php echo $row['font'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

---

Você estava usando `fetch`, que é usado para retornar uma unica linha [*DOC*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> Obtém a próxima linha de um conjunto de resultados

O correto seria `fetchAll` para retornar um array de vários itens [*DOC*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

> Retorna um array contendo **todas** as linhas do conjunto de resultados

---

**OBS**: Se você só vai fazer uso do *nome* da fonte, então troque `SELECT * FROM fontes` por `SELECT font FROM fontes`, e se pretende usar o *nome* da fonte e o *ID* então use `SELECT id, font FROM fontes`... Evite usar `SELECT *`

Comment: Papa irei editar a minha pergunta para vc. ver como ficou os códigos, e verificar se eu errei em algo, valeu?
E esta linha do SELECT '<?php } ?>', esta causando o erro "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/pbfjacar/public_html/teste/end.php on line 19".
Quando eu retiro-a ele me traz somente o ultimo item cadastrado.
Verifique no endereço de teste (http://www.pbfjacarepagua.com.br/teste/end.php)

Comment: Resolvido Papa, estávamos esquecendo de inserir uma chave na linha do "foreach", por isso estava dando o erro que mencionei no comentário anterior.
Bem resumindo, com a sua ajuda consegui puxar todos os itens da tabela fontes.
Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, abraços.